# YouTube iframe player getting error code 5

Tags: javascript, ios, html, youtube, youtube-api

Using the YouTube iframe player in an iOS UIWebView, I'm periodically seeing an onError event with error code 5 ("The requested content cannot be played in an HTML5 player or another error related to the HTML5 player has occurred").

The error is not associated with particular videos (that is, the video throwing the error plays just fine other times). Curiously, the errors often come in bursts: several videos in a row, from different channels, will throw the same error (each in a new UIWebView).

At some point, the error disappears, and the same video can be watched on the device that originally had the error. This has been going on for months.

Comment: Is there any update? I got the same weird issue with simple iframe-api on simple webpage.

Comment: I am also getting same issue , After this error other html5 video also not working for me. to work need to restart my application. Please share If you got solution